# What do these sigma subscripts represent?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, modeling

[image]

Axial strength for balsa wood at different densities

What I don't understand are the subscripts under the sigmas (strenghths.)
How do I know where the compression (crushing) and tensile strengths are? I'd like to know what represents what. Thank you!

Comment: What material is this for? Composites, foams? Giving some context for this data would help a lot in answering your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did put in the caption but it doesn't seem to have shown up. I just added it.

Comment: typically you would study the text acompanying the table to learn the nomenclature

Comment: I have looked through it, and I wrote down all the information there in the caption. Throughout the text the only related phrase is "axial strength."

Comment: I can assure you the original source of that data defined the symbols.  If your source is not adequate Id assume someone copied a table out of context, which is a dangerous thing to do.  Perhaps they provided a citation you can track down.

Answer (score 3):

Wood is anisotropic. Its mechanical properties are different in different directions relative to the grain of the wood.

The R, L and T suffixes probably refer to the radial, tangential, and longitudinal directions (defined relative to the tree, when the wood was still growing). See the diagram in http://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplgtr/fplgtr113/ch04.pdf.

I have no idea what the other subscripts might mean. I could guess some of them, but if you are making any serious use of this data, guessing is *always* the wrong option!